# How to set android imageview from downloaded png

Tags: android, png, imageview

I have a database online that gives image file locations and file names

I am trying to update an imageview in an android screen. Here is my code that gets the image and the things I have tried:

```
// successfully received product details
JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray("product"); // JSON Array

// get first product object from JSON Array
JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

// product with this pid found
// imageview
imageVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

// display data in imageview
//imageStr = "http://somesite.com/images/" + product.getString("imagefile");
imageStr = "file://somesite.com/images/" + product.getString("imagefile");

//imgUri=Uri.parse("file:///data/data/MYFOLDER/myimage.png");
//imgUri=Uri.parse(imageStr);
//imageVw.setImageURI(imgUri);
imageVw.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageStr));
```

Comment: Do you download a file or you have file stored somewhere on the web?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this if you want to get the Bitmap of the image stored on the web. I personally use the library called [ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/). The library is simple to use.

You have to understand that "A URL is a URI but a URI is not a URL. A URL is a specialization of URI that defines the network location of a specific representation for a given resource." so, if your file location is http then you need to make the function like below to get the Bitmap. I use ImageDownloader library because it runs its own thread and also manages some caches for faster image downloads.

```
  private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) { 
            Bitmap bm = null; 
            try { 
                URL aURL = new URL(url); 
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
                conn.connect(); 
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis); 
                bis.close(); 
                is.close(); 
           } catch (IOException e) { 
               Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e); 
           } 
           return bm; 
        }
```